# How to get the storage space usage in Firebase Database and file storage using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, firebase

I am building a web-app using JavaScript with Firebase Realtime Database and File-Storage. I am searching for the JavaScript API which find out available space in the specified Database and File-Storage , please help me if anyone has any idea around my requirement.

Answer (score 0):

One of the primary features of using google's firebase database was to provide application developers with an auto scalable database & storage without the need to write code on managing this storage space.

However, the simpler answer to the question would be to look at the size of the data downloaded in javascript and compare it with the quota limits of your plan. There is no google API, that tells you the storage availability in firebase. On reaching the quota/daily limits of your Spark or Flame plan, the firebase API, would throw exceptions/error. So using Blaze plan (pay as you go plan) gives you almost unlimited storage space.

When the resource is depleted, an attempt in the application to consume the resource results in an exception. This exception can be caught by the application and handled,  by displaying a friendly error message to the user.

In the Python API, this exception is apiproxy_errors.OverQuotaError...

Further reference: [Firebase Quotas](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/quotas)